# How do I get an Airtel Dongle working?

Tags: modem

How do I make airtel dongle work in ubuntu?

Comment: Someone on twitter said this answer worked, so I've edited the question so we can reopen this.

Answer (score 4):

Properly insert your dongle to the USB port; don't worry if it's not detected by Ubuntu.
Go to: Network Connection -> Mobile Broadband -> Add

Now there are 5 simple steps; select the natural options:

1. Select appropriate mobile device
2. Choose country provider/region
3. Choose your provider (airtel)
4. Choose your Billing Plan
5. Confirm Mobile broadband settings

see this [link](http://go3gonubuntu.blogspot.com/)